# "Hot Network Questions" - can one find out which posts were featured?

Tags: feature-request, support

Is it possible to find out which PuzzleSE posts were ever featured in the **Hot Network Questions** section?

(Obviously *after* they have been featured. Otherwise it is trivial!)

If not, that would be a nice feature to have...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no history for the HNQ list.

[Per a comment from an employee](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238445/add-an-audit-log-to-record-when-particular-question-enters-and-leaves-hot-list#comment781502_238445)

> We currently do not record anything about when a question enters/leaves the hot question list. The list is calculated on the fly each time (and heavily cached), so this will be a feature-request to add an audit log or something somewhere for that. –  Kasra Rahjerdi♦ Aug 22 '14 at 18:19